# proxy_pass to s3 presigned url with a php app on dokku / nginx

Tags: php, heroku, nginx, slim, dokku

Here's my use case:

I'm working with a S3 compatible storage provider which does not offer public-readable objects, only presigned links. I'm working with `Dokku`, `nginx` and the `heroku-php-buildpack`. My Application is based on the Slim PHP Framework.

I'm trying now to implement a function which is presigning the object and then sending the presigned assed to the browser via X-Accel-Redirect.

That means:

`www.example.com/asset/1/1/Sonnenuntergang-im-Meer_1400.jpg`

calls a script which returns the following header:

```
X-Accel-Redirect: /internal_redirect/storage.provider.ch/bucket/Sonnenuntergang-im-Meer_1400.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=xx&Expires=xx&Signature=xx
```

The /internal_redirect location is defined here:

```
location ~ ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
 internal;
 set $aws_access_key   'AWSAccessKeyId=$arg_AWSAccessKeyId';
 set $url_expires      'Expires=$arg_Expires';
 set $url_signature    'Signature=$arg_Signature';
 set $args_full        'https://$1/$2?$aws_access_key&$url_expires&$url_signature';
 proxy_set_header       Host $1;
 proxy_http_version     1.1;
 proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
 proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
 proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
 proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
 proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
 proxy_buffering        off;
 proxy_intercept_errors off;
 resolver               8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
 resolver_timeout       10s;
 proxy_pass             $args_full;
 #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
}
```

If I'm disabling `internal` and calling the url directly from the browser, it works. For that, I need to add the nginx configuration snipped into the nginx.conf.d subdir of the app root.

If I'm calling the script internally (with the header above) I'm getting the following error in the logs:

```
2016-09-01T14:30:27.229716973Z app[web.1]: 2016/09/01 14:30:27 [error] 230#0: 
*12 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named
location "@heroku-fcgi", client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, 
request: "GET /asset/1/1/Sonnenuntergang-im-Meer_1400.jpg HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/heroku.fcgi.5000.sock", host: "xxx.example.com"
```

My php script does basically not more than:

```
header('X-Accel-Redirect: /internal_redirect/' 
  . str_replace('https://', '', $this->db->presign_file($args['file']))
  . ';');
exit(0);
```

Whereas `presign_file`returns a string with the presigned file.

If I'm adding the nginx `location` snippet into the app specific configuration*, the behaviour is the same for internal and external calls. But it seems, that I can't use https for proxy_pass, which is necessary for my provider. Also options like `proxy_ssl_session_reuse off`, which look promising, are not allowed.

*) Defined in the Procfile with the option -C

Refs.:

- https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files
- http://kovyrin.net/2010/07/24/nginx-fu-x-accel-redirect-remote

**EDIT: More Infos about the nginx configuration**

The main file is gernerated by the buildpack:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php

whereas the position `include "<?=getenv('HEROKU_PHP_NGINX_CONFIG_INCLUDE')?>";` is substituded with this configuration file:

```
location ~ ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
  internal;
  set $aws_access_key   'AWSAccessKeyId=$arg_AWSAccessKeyId';
  set $url_expires      'Expires=$arg_Expires';
  set $url_signature    'Signature=$arg_Signature';
  set $args_full        'https://$1/$2?$aws_access_key&$url_expires&$url_signature';
  proxy_set_header       Host $1;
  proxy_http_version     1.1;
  proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_buffering        off;
  proxy_intercept_errors off;
  resolver               8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout       10s;
  proxy_pass             $args_full;
  #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
}


location / {
  # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
  try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
  # rewrite all to index.php
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
  try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
  internal;
}
```

Comment: The error implies that the rewrite loop is inside `location "@heroku-fcgi"`. It may be useful to see the entire `server` block.

Comment: Just added the configuration info...